# CKEditor Checkbox Default Value

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor's Enhanced Image plugin (image2) because it allows users to insert captioned images. However, I cannot enable the "captioned image" checkbox by default.

[image]

Setting a breakpoint after the code below shows the value is checked, but continuing unchecks it again.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
// Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
var dialogName = ev.data.name;
var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

if (dialogName == 'image2') {
    dialogDefinition.onShow = function() {
        captionField = this.getContentElement('info', 'hasCaption');
        captionField.setValue('checked');
        console.log(captionField);
        debugger;
    }
}
});
```

Any advice on how to tick a CKEditor checkbox by default is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tried updating the code based on Marek's answer to fit my needs, but the  `dialogShow` event doesn't seem to get called this way.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogShow', function( evt ) {
    var dialog = evt.data;
    if ( dialog._.name === 'image2' && !dialog.widget.isReady() ) {
        console.log('test');
        evt.data.getContentElement( 'info', 'hasCaption' ).setValue( true );
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems the checkbox is hidden and there is an image which changes color on check and unchecked.Not sure if you can see it from developer's tool

Comment: regarding an update: `dialogShow` doesn't work this way because it's called on editor instance, not the global namespace. I recommend playing with [CKEditor 4 API docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-dialogShow). If you don't want to use `CKEDITOR.replace` then you somehow need to get the editor instance. You can listen to `instanceReady` event _which is fired_ on a global namespace. And there you'd need to add `editor#dialogShow` listener. But we're going away from original question here.

Comment: Thanks for the update and pointing me in the right direction. I'm going to play around with the listeners some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dialogShow`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-dialogShow) event where you can modify dialog properties.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'image2',
    removePlugins: 'image',
    on: {
        dialogShow: function( evt ) {
            var dialog = evt.data;
            if ( dialog._.name === 'image2' && !dialog.widget.isReady() ) {
                evt.data.getContentElement( 'info', 'hasCaption' ).setValue( true );
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

Note the code where I'm checking on whether the widget actually exists, that's because you *don't* want to modify this checkbox if it is editing an existing widget.

For reason not known to me it the code doesn't work in builtin SO code platform, so all I can do is to drop [codepen link to check the code in action](https://codepen.io/mlewand/pen/pOZPmN).

Finally we're working on a solution that would be suitable for your case. You can track it at https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/2277

Comment: Thanks Marek. The code above checks the box, but causes some unwanted side effects. I have 05 editor instances on the page and CKEDITOR.replace() prevents the other instances from loading and sets a different toolbar outside of 'default' config. Would a variation of the code above (updated question) work?